# Thunderbird extension: accessing the value of mail-urlfield (xbl element)

Tags: javascript, plugins, xul, thunderbird

I'm playing with the thunderbird API, and I'm trying to create a button that would 'alert(url)' the content of the original website inside the RSS panel. AS far as I can see, the element is in https://github.com/mozilla/releases-comm-central/blob/master/suite/mailnews/msgHdrViewOverlay.xul

```
 <mail-urlfield id="expandedcontent-baseBox" label="&originalWebsite.label;" collapsed="true"/>
```

this mail-urlfield is defined as a XUL binding in https://github.com/mozilla/releases-comm-central/blob/a9cb7a6e8097e08c81eea8b3927fa82389a8a515/mail/base/content/mailWidgets.xml

```
 <binding id="mail-urlfield" extends="chrome://messenger/content/mailWidgets.xml#mail-headerfield">
    <content>
      <xul:description
                 onclick="if (event.button != 2)
                            openUILink(event.target.textContent, event);"
                 class="headerValue text-link headerValueUrl"
                 anonid="headerValue" flex="1" readonly="true"
                 role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" context="copyUrlPopup"/>
    </content>
  </binding>
```

document.getElementById return the "mail-urlfield" but on can I get the value of the element  ("http://....") ? ( I tried elt.label, elt.value ... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, got it:

```
var x = document.getElementById("expandedcontent-baseBox");
var y = document.getAnonymousElementByAttribute(x,"anonid","headerValue");
var www = y.textContent ;
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help others to understand the problem.